# Is it a good practice to use Redux-like pattern in native iOS apps?

Tags: ios, redux, redux-thunk, redux-saga

I'm plaining to apply Redux / Redux-Saga + coordinator pattern to my real released app, My app is very complex and including several modules.

It confuses me is that how to design a good state tree? And this state tree is easy to extend. Is't too heavy to keep data of all modules in the state object?

My app is not developed via RN but native OC & swift.

Comment: I read some blog posts, but most of them are about JS / web,  almost none of them is on mobile native app.  Anyone would share what's the good practice of Redux in native iOS?

Answer (score 1):

You'll definitely find use for some kind of state machine that can keep track of transitions in concurrent systems. Though, I can hardly imagine how you could use `redux` or any of it's middleware, short of running something like a web view and having it communicate with the main application process, so try to find something that's actually been developed for the platform that you're using to get a great experience.

And no, there's no issue with keeping all the data in a single object. Think about it: the data that your application needs has to be allocated somewhere, so it doesn't matter whether it is assigned on a single object or spread accross multiple ones. Usually what happens between transitions is that you always get a new state object and only the path to the parts which have changed are invalidated, while the other references are just copied over.

This makes it a lot easier to reason about the application state (all of it is there) and perform other optimizations (re-render only those view components/derivatives for which the sate has been updated).

Comment: Thanks @Filip,  The reason I am going to try Redux in my project is just because Redux is unidirection data flow,  and this can make things more simple and easier.  But it seems few real world native app using this pattern?